# Can you identify ways to optimise this postgres search query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

We have a search query that returns thousands of results. These results are plotted on a google map with custom markers. When I run `EXPAIN ANALYSE`, it returns an execution time of 34086.310 ms. I would like to optimise the performance of this query.

Please note: currently there are no indexes applied.

I have tried:

- If I remove distance criteria I can reduce execution time to 15425.492 ms
- If I keep distance criteria but reduce max radius to 10000 I can reduce execution time to 13138.633 ms

Clearly implementing pagination with a smaller distance radius is the way forward, but are there any other ways to optimise the query?

Help interpreting the query plan, or any suggestions for optimising the query will be greatly received.

Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON ("Users"."id") "Users".*, "UserData".*, "BusinessKeywords"."keyword",
ST_DistanceSphere(ST_MakePoint(53.483959, -2.244644), "UserData"."location") AS distance 
FROM "UserData" 
INNER JOIN "Users" ON "UserData"."UserId" = "Users"."id"
INNER JOIN "BusinessKeywords" ON array_position("Users"."keywordIds", "BusinessKeywords"."id") > 0
WHERE "Users"."userType" = 'business' 
AND ST_DistanceSphere(ST_MakePoint(53.483959, -2.244644), "UserData"."location") < 10000000
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT ON ("Users"."id") "Users".*, "UserData".*,"BusinessKeywords"."keyword",
ST_DistanceSphere(ST_MakePoint(53.483959, -2.244644), "UserData"."location") AS distance 
FROM "BusinessKeywords", "UserData" INNER JOIN "Users" ON "UserData"."UserId" = "Users"."id"
WHERE "Users"."userType" = 'business' 
AND ST_DistanceSphere(ST_MakePoint(53.483959, -2.244644), "UserData"."location") < 10000000
```

Query Plan:

```
Unique  (cost=611298.43..612468.43 rows=5200 width=25720) (actual time=33956.094..33991.406 rows=5106 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=611298.43..611311.43 rows=5200 width=25720) (actual time=33956.091..33957.167 rows=5110 loops=1)
        Sort Key: lots of fields... (_st_distance('0101000020E61000006CCD565EF2BD4A400E4DD9E907F501C0'::geography, geography("UserData".location), '0'::double precision, false))
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 3942kB
        ->  Append  (cost=836.33..496583.48 rows=5200 width=25720) (actual time=62.378..33321.472 rows=5110 loops=1)
              ->  Unique  (cost=836.33..138031.12 rows=2600 width=2772) (actual time=62.377..6266.604 rows=2562 loops=1)
                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=836.33..136918.31 rows=445124 width=2772) (actual time=62.366..6229.167 rows=16393 loops=1)
                          Join Filter: (array_position("Users"."keywordIds", "BusinessKeywords".id) > 0)
                          Rows Removed by Join Filter: 3952715
                          ->  Merge Join  (cost=836.33..1114.22 rows=866 width=2752) (actual time=57.005..125.258 rows=2574 loops=1)
                                Merge Cond: ("Users".id = "UserData"."UserId")
                                ->  Index Scan using "Users_pkey" on "Users"  (cost=0.28..258.61 rows=2600 width=252) (actual time=0.042..31.085 rows=2600 loops=1)
                                      Filter: ("userType" = 'business'::"enum_Users_userType")
                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 38
                                ->  Sort  (cost=836.05..838.25 rows=879 width=2500) (actual time=56.923..60.325 rows=2577 loops=1)
                                      Sort Key: "UserData"."UserId"
                                      Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 1109kB
                                      ->  Seq Scan on "UserData"  (cost=0.00..793.07 rows=879 width=2500) (actual time=0.699..46.392 rows=2603 loops=1)
                                            Filter: (_st_distance('0101000020E61000006CCD565EF2BD4A400E4DD9E907F501C0'::geography, geography(location), '0'::double precision, false) < '10000000'::double precision)
                                            Rows Removed by Filter: 35
                          ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..45.13 rows=1542 width=16) (actual time=0.000..0.266 rows=1542 loops=2574)
                                ->  Seq Scan on "BusinessKeywords"  (cost=0.00..37.42 rows=1542 width=16) (actual time=0.028..2.543 rows=1542 loops=1)
              ->  Unique  (cost=836.33..358500.36 rows=2600 width=2772) (actual time=32.689..27049.903 rows=2548 loops=1)
                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=836.33..355160.62 rows=1335893 width=2772) (actual time=32.679..25895.837 rows=3929016 loops=1)
                          ->  Merge Join  (cost=836.33..1114.22 rows=866 width=2752) (actual time=32.229..124.206 rows=2548 loops=1)
                                Merge Cond: ("Users_1".id = "UserData_1"."UserId")
                                ->  Index Scan using "Users_pkey" on "Users" "Users_1"  (cost=0.28..258.61 rows=2600 width=252) (actual time=0.029..40.841 rows=2600 loops=1)
                                      Filter: ("userType" = 'business'::"enum_Users_userType")
                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 38
                                ->  Sort  (cost=836.05..838.25 rows=879 width=2500) (actual time=32.174..36.228 rows=2550 loops=1)
                                      Sort Key: "UserData_1"."UserId"
                                      Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 1097kB
                                      ->  Seq Scan on "UserData" "UserData_1"  (cost=0.00..793.07 rows=879 width=2500) (actual time=0.458..22.525 rows=2576 loops=1)
                                            Filter: (_st_distance('0101000020E61000006CCD565EF2BD4A400E4DD9E907F501C0'::geography, geography(location), '0'::double precision, false) < '1000000'::double precision)
                                            Rows Removed by Filter: 62
                          ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..45.13 rows=1542 width=12) (actual time=0.001..0.397 rows=1542 loops=2548)
                                ->  Seq Scan on "BusinessKeywords" "BusinessKeywords_1"  (cost=0.00..37.42 rows=1542 width=12) (actual time=0.020..1.389 rows=1542 loops=1)
```

Comment: The Cartesian product in the second subquery seems like a performance killer.

Comment: *`EXPAIN ANAYSE`* - is your L key broken? :)

Comment: What indexes are on the table?  Is there an index on UserData.location?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Right, so I guess refactor using `WITH` query?

Comment: @Jeremy there are  no indexes currently

Comment: As @GordonLinoff said, that cartesian product is a big issue.  You are generating almost 4 million rows and then narrowing that down to ~2600 by randomly selecting one row per "Users"."id".  That seems to be both a bad idea and unintentional.  I think fixing that query to do what you actually want it to do will help a lot.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to shave over 30 seconds off the query run time by using unest instead of  array_position: `Execution time: 3642.039 ms`

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON ("Users"."id") "Users".*, "UserData".*, "BusinessKeywords"."keyword",
ST_DistanceSphere(ST_MakePoint(53.483959, -2.244644), "UserData"."location") AS distance 
FROM "UserData" 
INNER JOIN "Users" ON "UserData"."UserId" = "Users"."id"
INNER JOIN (select "Users"."id", unnest("Users"."keywordIds") AS "kwid" from "Users") AS "BusinessKeywordsXR" ON "BusinessKeywordsXR"."id" = "Users"."id" INNER JOIN "BusinessKeywords" ON "BusinessKeywordsXR"."kwid" = "BusinessKeywords"."id"
WHERE "Users"."userType" = 'business' 
AND ST_DistanceSphere(ST_MakePoint(53.483959, -2.244644), "UserData"."location") < 10000000
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT ON ("Users"."id") "Users".*, "UserData".*,"BusinessKeywords"."keyword",
ST_DistanceSphere(ST_MakePoint(53.483959, -2.244644), "UserData"."location") AS distance 
FROM "UserData" INNER JOIN "Users" ON "UserData"."UserId" = "Users"."id"
INNER JOIN (select "Users"."id", unnest("Users"."keywordIds") AS "kwid" from "Users") AS "BusinessKeywordsXR" ON "BusinessKeywordsXR"."id" = "Users"."id" INNER JOIN "BusinessKeywords" ON "BusinessKeywordsXR"."kwid" = "BusinessKeywords"."id"
WHERE "Users"."userType" = 'business' 
AND ST_DistanceSphere(ST_MakePoint(53.483959, -2.244644), "UserData"."location") < 10000000
```

Comment: I think you can remove that derived table with the UNNEST completely: http://dpaste.com/01VX1H4 - maybe that even removes the need for `distinct on ()` as well

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name `ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "BusinessKeywordsXR"` I am generating "BusinessKeywordsXR" on the fly with UNNEST, as I am restricted from changing the DB model.

Comment: Copy and paste error: http://dpaste.com/1QN9J5E all those dreaded double quotes make this really hard to read